# RunTime exception for Converting String to Boolean

Tags: apex, exception

```
Public static void createDiscrepancy(Id ndcId,Map<object,String> mapOfParameters){
                                         try
                                         {

                                            list<string> valuesFromMap = mapOfParameters.values();

                                             system.debug('mapOfParameters '+mapOfParameters.values());

                                             //system.debug('EMIInputValue '+emiInputValue);
                                             Boolean emiMismatch = valuesFromMap[0];
                                             Boolean tenureMismatch = Boolean.valueOf(valuesFromMap[1]);
                                             Boolean disbursementMismatch = Boolean.valueOf(valuesFromMap[2]);

                                            Boolean customerNameMisMatch = Boolean.valueOf(valuesFromMap[3]);
                                            Boolean dealerMisMatch =  Boolean.valueOf(valuesFromMap[4]);
```

Hi,

Here i am trying to convert String to Boolean value..

So it is giving me runtime exception when i am trying to update the object.

> Invalid conversion from runtime type Boolean to String

I am getting paramertes from js controller in map and assigning to list and then assigning each value to object field..

Is that legal what i am doing? What is wrong here..
**Boolean.valueOf(valuesFromMap[1]);**

Comment: On which line is this error being thrown? It looks like you're trying to convert a String to a Boolean, but the value is already a Boolean.

Comment: oh yes my bad String to Boolean..Correct...and the error is in   Boolean emiMismatch = Boolean.valueOf(valuesFromMap[0]); line

Comment: in above code that line is wrong i removed and forgot to add again

Comment: You can surely convert String to Boolean using the method you used. However the output should return a Boolean value  like this Boolean b = Boolean.valueOf('true');                                                                          If you do Boolean emiMismatch = Boolean.valueOf('str');, it will not return a Boolean. So I am not sure the intent of what you have written.

Comment: Thanks Dave...But i am storing it in boolean only and valuesFromMap is a map of <object ,string> from which i am taking values which are strings and converting them to boolean

Comment: Is your code updated? Your post says `Boolean emiMismatch = valuesFromMap[0];`  which will end up in error for sure, and the in comments above you mentioned `Boolean emiMismatch = Boolean.valueOf(valuesFromMap[0]);`, which should work fine as long as you have the valuesFromMap[0] returning a string true or false.

Comment: yes my ccode is updated..That was wrongly entered.If you see other params i am converting string to boolean..Its saving but during runtime it is throwing me exception